# Сохранение данных в NSUserDefaults

Tags: массивы, swift, nsuserdefaults

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста справится с задачей.
При каждом нажатии кнопки "Сохранить", несколько полей (строки) сохраняю в словарь, словарь кладу в массив. Получаю массив, наполненный словарями

```
@IBOutlet weak var field1: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var field2: UITextField!


var myData: [String : String] = [:]
var arrayAllData : [Dictionary<String, String>] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

func saveData() {

    if field1.text?.characters.count != 0 && field2.text?.characters.count != 0 {

        myData["oneData"] = field1.text
        myData["twoData"] = field2.text

        arrayAllData.append(myData)

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(arrayAllData, forKey: "allData")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        print(myData)
        print(arrayAllData)
    }
    field1.text = nil
    field2.text = nil
}

@IBAction func saveDutton(sender: UIButton) {
    saveData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Как, используя NSUserDefaults, сохранить данные, чтобы при следующем входе в приложение, в массив добавлялись новые словари, а старые оставались?

Comment: Вам надо при запуске прочитать, что у вас уже сохранено, добавить новые поля и пересохранить

Comment: Спасибо. Решение нашел.

let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("allData")! as! [Dictionary<String, String>])
arrayAllData = data

/*
.......
*/

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(arrayAllData, forKey: "allData")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

Comment: ну публикуйте ответ - может кому пригодится